# Nuget - Give feed when listing packages according to search

Tags: powershell, cmd, nuget

I'm using Nuget in CLI and I was wondering if there was any way to show from which feed a package comes from.

At the moment, I'm listing all packages having the string I searched for to find the one I'm looking for (with `| sls` in powershell, I can filter those results). Then, haing the wanted pakage, I would list all feeds and then I will search each feed that is most likely to have the searched package.

```
nuget list pckg_name | sls version_number
nuget sources | sls product_name
nuget list pckg_name -source most_likely_feed_where_package_will_be_found
```

As you would expect, this is very tidious, specially when I have no clue in which feed the said package is to be found... Any clues on how to list the feed in where packages are when using `nuget list` ?

Comment: how many public feeds (like nuget.org) do you have configured? This to understand if you have dependencies on sources that either have packages with the same ID, or if you have no control over what packages are in the feed.
And finally what is it that you are trying to achieve by finding which feed the package came from?

Comment: I'm not certain, but we do have over a hundred feeds at the moment with different types (nom, nuget, bower, etc.). Regarding the ID, I really do not know if there are duplication in IDs over the feed...
What I'm trying to achieve is to install the package that I'm looking for

Comment: there are multiple ways to install a package to a project. The reasons is because the eco-system today is fragmented on what package management format a project uses to maintain a list of the nuget package references.
1) packages.config (the old way) - an explicit file with that name will be present in the project which will have a list of all the package references.
2) package reference (the new way) - references live in the project file such as the .csproj.

Q. What bucket are you in?

Comment: PS: if you know the package ID, `nuget install package-id` should just work. You don't need to specify the feed. NuGet will do that for you.